Azure DevOps - Get consumed artifacts for a YAML pipeline run via REST API
I have a YAML release pipeline which triggers from a build pipeline. I want to get the details about the consumed artifacts via REST API. E.g., Consumed artifacts of all types such as repositories, builds, etc as shown below:


I tried the Runs - Get REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-7.0
But it seem to return the consumed artifacts of only repository type.

I attempt with the same REST API "Runs - Get", and it can correctly return the resource pipeline as expected.

The YAML of the pipeline. The YAML pipeline will be automatically triggered once a run of the resource pipeline (MathCalc in below sample) is completed successfully.
# azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MathCalc
    source: MathCalc
    trigger: true

. . .



Call the REST API "Runs - Get" in PowerShell script.
# get-pipleine-run.ps1

$organization = "Organization Name"
$project = "Project Name"
$pipelineId = 174
$runId = 3818
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/${organization}/${project}/_apis/pipelines/${pipelineId}/runs/${runId}?api-version=7.0"

$pat = "Personal Access Token"
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File -FilePath run-$runId.json





EDIT:
I also tried the REST API "Runs - Get" on my Azure DevOps Server 2022, and it also can return the resource pipeline as expected.

The YAML pipeline with schedules trigger.
# azure-pipelines.yml

trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: '54 6 * * *'
  displayName: 'Daily Trigger'
  branches:
    include:
    - main

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MathCalc
    source: MathCalc
    trigger: none

. . .



The PowerShell script to Call the REST API.
# get-pipleine-run.ps1

$instance = "Server Name"
$collection = "DefaultCollection"
$project = "BrightRanProj"
$pipelineId = 8
$runId = 31
$uri = "https://${instance}/${collection}/${project}/_apis/pipelines/${pipelineId}/runs/${runId}?api-version=7.0"

$pat = "Personal Access Token"
$base64Token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
$headers = @{Authorization = "Basic $base64Token"}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Out-File -FilePath run-$runId.json






I am using Azure Devops Server 2022, somehow I'm not getting pipeline resources.
The YAML release runs are scheduled runs and not CI runs but it should not matter, right?

@osim_ans, Yes, as long as you have set the resource pipeline in the YAML pipeline, no matter how the pipeline run is triggered, it can list the resource pipeline. I will try the API on my Azure DevOps Server 2022 and give you an update later.

@osim_ans, I attempted on my Azure DevOps Server 2022, and the API also can return the resource pipeline as expected. See EDIT in my above answer.

Ok, thanks.. Which version of Azure DevOps Server are you using?
https://${instance}/${collection}/_home/About

@osim_ans, From the URL you mentioned (https://${instance}/${collection}/_home/About), I can see the current version of my Azure DevOps Server 2022 is "Version Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 (AzureDevOpsServer_20231109.2)". It is not the latest version, but it can work fine.

@osim_ans, If your Azure DevOps Server 2022 is not the latest version, you can try to upgrade it to the latest, and then try the API again.

Thanks, Just verified it. It doesn't works in the Version Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1 but works in the latest versions perfectly. Maybe it was fixed by MS recently    :)
